# Initializing static member causing `Missing type specifier - int assumed.`

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T> class kickingMyself {
public:
    static int a;
};

template <class T> kickingMyself<T>::a = 0;

int main() {
    kickingMyself<int>::a = 4;
    cout << kickingMyself<int>::a << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

on the line:

```
template <class T> kickingMyself<T>::a = 0;
```

Im getting the following error:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I don't know why I'm getting this error. please help.

Comment: The error message actually says **exactly** what the error is and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the type, which should be `int`:

```
template <class T>
int kickingMyself<T>::a = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks!! Do I have to specity the type for every class, or for template classes only?

Comment: @user1798362 Yo don’t specify the type for the class (that wouldn’t make sense) – you specify the type for the *variable*. The syntax for a variable definition *always* requires the type.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if the class is templated or not. You specify the type when defining methods or declaring static class members.